# EXC_ARITHMETIC Error With Nonzero Denominator - XCode

Tags: c, xcode, division

Usually, when I get an `EXC_ARITHMETIC` error, it means I divided by zero, which makes sense to me. However, this time I have no idea what is going on. Here is a function that is being called rather frequently:

```c
GP_TYPE GP_NodeFunction_Divide(GP_Node* node, GP_Mem* mem, void* data){

    /* These are just normal function calls.
       I can say with some certainty they are not misbehaving. */
    GP_TYPE denom = GP_Call(node->next[1], mem, data);
    GP_TYPE num = GP_Call(node->next[0], mem, data);

    if (denom) {
        /* denom != 0, right? */
        return num / denom; /* Crash! EXC_ARITHMETIC */
    }

    else return 1e12;
}
```

My program runs for several minutes with no incident, presumably calling this functions hundreds of thousands of times, but will still crash here occasionally.

`GP_TYPE` is defined as follows:

```c
#ifdef GP_USE_DOUBLE
#define GP_TYPE double
#else
#define GP_TYPE int
#endif
```

`GP_USE_DOUBLE` is NOT defined.

I've been compiling with `-O0`, and XCode's debug window holds this information at the crash site:

```c
...
num = (int)-2147483648
denom = (int)-1
...
```

This information is consistent. Every time this function crashes, the values of `num` and `denom` are the same.

I tried to specifically type `num / denom` into the debug window as an expression, and XCode promptly crashed (Which, I suppose, is not the weirdest thing about this bug).

I can also navigate the debug window to observe the `GP_Node* node`, and it has been a valid pointer, with valid elements, every time it crashes.

Is XCode's debug window bugged? (I've just recently updated to XCode 6.3.2)

Is `denom` secretly `0`? Is this even possible?

Is there another way to get an `EXC_ARITHMETIC` from a division of `int`s?

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `num` happens to be the most negative number that can be represented by a signed 32-bit variable (assuming 2's complement); unfortunately for you, the most positive number that can be so represented is 2147483647 - one less than -2147483648/-1.

Comment: Huh. So it throws an `EXC_ARITHMETIC` instead of a simple overflow? Will a check like `if(denom && !(num == -2147483648 && denom == -1)) ...` remedy the problem?

Comment: suggest adding code to check for special cases and returning an appropriate result for those special cases.